# JSON-LD not visible in Google Search Console

Tags: schema.org, google-search-console, json-ld

I have a JSON-LD in my site, but it is not visible in the Google Search Console.

The URL that has the structured data in is: http://jdcomputers.cz/

```
<script type="application/ld+json">

    {  "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url" : "http://www.jdcomputers.cz",
      "logo" : "http://www.jdcomputers.cz/soubory/logo_small_jdc.png",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "Nové Město nad Metují, CZ",
        "postalCode": "549 01",
        "streetAddress": "Náchodská 464"
      },
      "email": "jd(at)jdcomputers.cz",
      "brand": "Software online, ekonomický a informační webový systém, specializované zakázkové aplikace",
      "faxNumber": "491 470 372",
      "name": "JD Computers",
      "telephone": "491 470 372",
      "sameAs" : [
        "https://twitter.com/systemdodo",
        "https://plus.google.com/+JdcomputersCzSoftware",
        "https://www.facebook.com/jdcomputersczsoftware"
      ]}
</script>
```

and http://jdcomputers.cz/softwareprohelpdesk.html

```
<script type="application/ld+json">

{  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "SoftwareApplication",
  "url" : "http://jdcomputers.cz/softwareprohelpdesk.html",
  "image": "http://dodo.is/images/dodo_informacni_system.gif",
  "screenshot" : "http://jdcomputers.cz/soubory/SoftwareHelpdeskGraphReport.jpg",
  "applicationCategory":"Helpdesk, Podpora, CRM, Ekonomický systém, Informační systém",
  "applicationSubCategory" : "Helpdesk, CRM",
  "operatingSystem":"Operating systems supported - server (Windows, Linux) client (Windows, Linux, Android, OSX)",
  "name": "Software helpdesk a podpora Dodo",
  "about":"Dodo online informační systém pro podporu zákazníků a firemních procesů",
  "keywords":"Software, aplikace, systém, DoDo, Helpdesk, CRM, Podpora",
  "description":"Dodo webový online software pro podporu zákazníků a firemních procesů od společnosti JD Computers",
  "author":{
        "@type": "Organization",
    "url" : "http://www.jdcomputers.cz",
    "logo" : "http://www.jdcomputers.cz/soubory/logo_small_jdc.png",
    "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "addressLocality": "Nové Město nad Metují, CZ",
            "postalCode": "549 01",
            "streetAddress": "Náchodská 464"
    },
    "email": "jd(at)jdcomputers.cz",
    "brand": "Software online, ekonomický a informační webový systém, specializované zakázkové aplikace",
    "faxNumber": "491 470 372",
    "name": "JD Computers",
    "telephone": "491 470 372",
    "sameAs" : [
            "https://vk.com/jdcomputers",
            "https://jdcomputers.tumblr.com",
            "https://twitter.com/systemdodo",
            "https://plus.google.com/+JdcomputersCzSoftware",
            "https://www.facebook.com/jdcomputersczsoftware"
    ]
  },
  "sameAs" : [
    "https://twitter.com/systemdodo",
    "https://vk.com/dodosys",
    "https://plus.google.com/+DodoIsSystem",
    "https://www.facebook.com/systemdodo"
  ]}
</script>
```

Using Google test tool, it shows that the data is ok.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Structured Data in the Google Search Console seems always to be some days behind. F.e. when I last did an update on the website, it took some days until the changes were reflected within the Google Search Console. Is it there in the meantime?